# modal spans out of browser when browser sized too small

Tags: html, css

I have a simple modal on my page, when I resize the browser it adjusts to its size, **the problem** is when the browsers say 'height' is over the modal element, the top bit seems to 'go out' of the browser, so essentially you cant see that bit part..

I experimented with setting the `overflow` and `max-height` on my `#content-container` and `#wrapper` but Its completely ineffective, what am I doing wrong?

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kmav8ox7/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="content-container">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <ul id="flex-container">
      <li class="flex-item">
        <div id="list-area"></div>
      </li>
      <li class="flex-item">
        <div id="img-desc-container">
          <div class="image-area">
            <img src="http://dukes-lancaster.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/placeholder.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="description-area"></div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
/* center content */

#content-container {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  border: 3px solid red;
  /* positioning */
  margin-top: 50vh;
  margin-left: 50vw;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

  max-height: 100%;

}

/* wrapp content */

#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
   max-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  /*Centering content*/
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: content;
}

#img-desc-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

/*  MULTI ELEMENT */

.image-area,
.description-area {
  width: 200px;
  height: 125px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.image-area,
.description-area,
#list-area {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 10px;
}

/* LIST AREA */

#list-area {
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #22AED1;
  float: left;
}

/* IMG AREA */

.image-area {
  background-color: #016FB9;
}

.image-area img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

/* DESC AREA */

.description-area {
  background-color: #AFA98D;
  height: 105px;
}

/*FLEX CONTAINER */

#flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you.
You need to change some css of `#content-container`. change `translate(-50%, 50%)` to `translate(-50%, 0%)` and remove `margin-top`

```css
/* center content */
body {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   min-height: 100vh;
}
#content-container {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    border: 3px solid red;
    margin-left: 50vw;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
}

/* wrapp content */

#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  /*Centering content*/
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: content;
}

#img-desc-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

/*  MULTI ELEMENT */

.image-area,
.description-area {
  width: 200px;
  height: 125px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.image-area,
.description-area,
#list-area {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 10px;
}

/* LIST AREA */

#list-area {
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #22AED1;
  float: left;
}

/* IMG AREA */

.image-area {
  background-color: #016FB9;
}

.image-area img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

/* DESC AREA */

.description-area {
  background-color: #AFA98D;
  height: 105px;
}

/*FLEX CONTAINER */

#flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<div id="content-container">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <ul id="flex-container">
      <li class="flex-item">
        <div id="list-area"></div>
      </li>
      <li class="flex-item">
        <div id="img-desc-container">
          <div class="image-area">
            <img src="http://dukes-lancaster.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/placeholder.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="description-area"></div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I still need it to be centered vertically

Comment: @Shayer please check the updated answer, open snippet in `full page` to see it in action

Comment: excuse for the delay, thank you for your elegant answer

Answer (score 0):

I  think you can use this css code for solution.

```
#content-container {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    border: 3px solid red;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 50vw;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
}
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 94vh;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: content;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make it Responsive, You must avoid using Pixels to provide height or width.
U can Give Height in Percentage (for eg. 100% for maximum), then it will never get out of the page